# Oracle PL SQL Procedure takes long time to complete, after the very last statement in the procedure is processed

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, execution-time

We are using Oracle 11.2.0.4.0.
We created a procedure to do update a CLOB column in a table for all available rows.

We have a DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE statement to print SYSDATE at the very last line of the Procedure.

When we execute this procedure, it takes long time to complete after the last line has printed the SYSDATE.

Not sure if I am missing anything. Any help would be much appreciated

We tried executing the procedure by having `DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSDATE)` statements inside the procedure to debug/find the pain points.

This is how we executed the procedure and pasted the output at the end:

```
SET TIMING ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

SELECT 'Outside block Start time: ' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') OUTSIDEBLOCKSTARTTIME from dual;
DECLARE
  I_LIMIT BINARY_INTEGER;
  I_STR_TO_REPLACE VARCHAR2(200);
  I_REPLACEMENT_STR VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  I_LIMIT := 10000;
  I_STR_TO_REPLACE := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
  I_REPLACEMENT_STR := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';

  P_TEST_CLOB_MASK(
    I_LIMIT => I_LIMIT,
    I_STR_TO_REPLACE => I_STR_TO_REPLACE,
    I_REPLACEMENT_STR => I_REPLACEMENT_STR
  );

END;
/
SELECT 'Outside block End time: ' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') OUTSIDEBLOCKENDTIME from dual;
```

Below is the code for Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test_clob_mask (
   i_limit             IN   PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1000,
   i_str_to_replace    IN   VARCHAR2
         DEFAULT 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',
   i_replacement_str   IN   VARCHAR2
         DEFAULT 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
)
IS
   CURSOR cur_fetch_cddaddcomphistory
   IS
      SELECT ROWID row_id, ua4cf_cddaddcomphistory ua4cf_cddaddcomphistory
        FROM generic_set11
       WHERE ua4cf_cddaddcomphistory IS NOT NULL;
   l_limit                NUMBER         := 0;
   l_counter              NUMBER         := 0;
   l_rowid                ROWID;
   l_hold_clob            CLOB;
   l_masked_clob          CLOB;
   l_length_clob          NUMBER         := 0;
   l_str_to_replace       VARCHAR2 (500);
   l_replacement_str      VARCHAR2 (500);
   l_overall_start_dt     DATE;
   l_batch_start_dt       DATE           := NULL;
   l_batch_time_taken     NUMBER         := 0;
   l_overall_time_taken   NUMBER         := 0;
BEGIN
   l_overall_start_dt := SYSDATE;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'Overall Start: '
                         || TO_CHAR (l_overall_start_dt,
                                     'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'
                                    )
                        );
   l_str_to_replace := i_str_to_replace;
   l_replacement_str := i_replacement_str;
   l_limit           := i_limit;

   OPEN cur_fetch_cddaddcomphistory;

   LOOP
      FETCH cur_fetch_cddaddcomphistory
       INTO l_rowid, l_hold_clob;

      EXIT WHEN cur_fetch_cddaddcomphistory%NOTFOUND;
      l_counter := l_counter + 1;
      l_length_clob := DBMS_LOB.getlength (l_hold_clob);
      DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_masked_clob, TRUE);
      DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_masked_clob,
                            l_length_clob,
                            TRANSLATE (l_hold_clob,
                                       i_str_to_replace,
                                       i_replacement_str
                                      )
                           );

      UPDATE generic_set11
         SET ua4cf_cddaddcomphistory = l_masked_clob
       WHERE ROWID = l_rowid;

      IF MOD (l_counter, l_limit) = 0
      THEN
         COMMIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cur_fetch_cddaddcomphistory;

   COMMIT;
   l_overall_time_taken :=
                        TRUNC (((SYSDATE - l_overall_start_dt) * 24 * 60), 2);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'Overall End: '
                         || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
                         || ' - Time taken in Mins: '
                         || l_overall_time_taken
                         || ' - Counters: '
                         || l_counter
                        );
END p_test_clob_mask;
/
```

Our expectation is that after the last `DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE` is completed, the procedure should complete.

But the Elapsed time says 20+ minutes, where as per the last `DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE`statement, the time taken was only 3 Minutes

Below is the output:

```
OUTSIDEBLOCKSTARTTIME
-------------------------------------------------------
Outside block Start time: 27-DEC-2018 15:33:45

Elapsed: 00:00:00.118
Overall Start: 27-DEC-18 15:33:45
Overall End: 27-DEC-18 15:37:37 - Time taken in Mins: 3.86 - Counters: 138913


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:20:19.313

OUTSIDEBLOCKENDTIME
-----------------------------------------------------
Outside block End time: 27-DEC-2018 15:54:04

Elapsed: 00:00:00.095
```

Comment: It looks to me as if you're creating a lot of temporary `CLOB`s.  Does it help if you free them using [`DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i1012980)?

Comment: Another idea is to create one temporary `CLOB` outside the loop and erase it at the beginning (or end) of each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @LukeWoodward You nailed it. I have added `DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_masked_clob);` at the of the LOOP. And now the procedure completes immediately after the last `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` got executed
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, the fix was to add the line

```
    DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(l_masked_clob);
```

at the end of the loop.  This ensures that the temporary `CLOB`s used are cleaned up as they are used.  The code as written causes Oracle to create a new temporary `CLOB` for each iteration of the loop, and it is likely that the cleanup of all of these temporary `CLOB`s (possibly hundreds or even thousands of them) at the end of the block is causing the delay.

Another possible performance boost could be obtained by creating one temporary `LOB` outside of the loop, clearing it (e.g. using `DBMS_LOB.erase` or `DBMS_LOB.trim`) at the end of each iteration of the loop, and freeing it at the end.